# Why are multiple Pushion Passenger instances running and app is not loaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I am suffering from passenger configuration after using AMI. (Amazon image - I created the image of what was running properly and launched the new instance, but it can't be accessed via 80 port).

After command

```
passenger stop
```

and

```
passenger-status
```

the message is

```
*** Cleaning stale instance directory /tmp/passenger.P3W4gmK
    Warning: Operation not permitted @ rb_file_chown - /tmp/passenger.P3W4gmK/.
Version : 5.3.5
Date    : 2019-06-25 09:48:54 +0000
Instance: Cm0CL6zm (nginx/1.12.1 Phusion_Passenger/5.1.8)

Phusion Passenger is currently not serving any applications.
```

then if I try to restart the app with

passenger-config restart-app .

then,

```
*** Cleaning stale instance directory /tmp/passenger.P3W4gmK
    Warning: Operation not permitted @ rb_file_chown - /tmp/passenger.P3W4gmK/.
There are no Phusion Passenger-served applications running whose paths begin with '/var/www/companyname/code'.
You have new mail in /var/spool/mail/ec2-user
```

What am I missing here? :(

Please share any idea with me!.!

Comment: It may fix - sudo chmod o+t -R /tmp

Answer (score 4):

There is an issue with the permissions. I encountered the same error and the way to fix it was to run the command (`passenger-config restart-app`) with a user from the sudo group. It then deletes the tmp/ files and you won't encounter such message on the next restart.